# Is it possiblet to call async function from xaml directly

Tags: c#, uwp

My code shows as below

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" SelectionChanged="comboBox1OnClick">
```

then

```
public async Task comboBox1OnClick(object sender)//public void comboBox1OnClick(object sender) is Ok
        {

            await messageBoxs_Show("hello");
}
```

It will report error:

```
No overload for comboBox1OnClick matches delegate 'SelectionChangedEventHandler'
```

Just wonder if it is possiblet to call async function from xaml directly?

Your comment welcome

Comment: You have to make it async void (this is one of the rare exception where you can do it)

Comment: what's wrong if you just call it in autogenerated eventhandler, except you type a few more lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have missed [`SelectionChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.selectionchangedeventargs?view=winrt-22000) parameter for [`SelectionChangedEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.selectionchangedeventhandler?view=winrt-22000), please edit your comboBox1OnClick like the following.

```
private async void comboBox1OnClick(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   await messageBoxs_Show("hello");
}
```